# Formatting input (removing leading zeros and decimal places) in C90?

Tags: c, int, string-formatting, c89

```
#include <stdio.h>

int intVal(int x)
{
    if(x < '0' || x > '9'){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        x = x - '0';
        return x;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int c, num, prev;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        num = (intVal(prev) * 10) + intVal(c);
        prev = num;
        printf("%d", num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do with this program is input an arbitrary number to be read a char at a time, then format it into an int so that I can work with it (Don't want to use printf formatting)  Also, I am only allowed to use getchar and printf for this assignment.

Sample Input: 0001234.5
*edit* Desired Output: <1234>(5)
Actual Output: 0001234050

I feel like I'm on the cusp of an epiphany but I've hit a roadblock, please help?

*edit I forgot to mention that the END result I am going for is to have the non-decimal numbers enclosed in <1234> and the decimal numbers in brackets (5)

Comment: if desired out put is 1234.5, why are you using int to store your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- For a start, you're calling `intVal()` on `prev`, which is going to do all sorts of crazy things.
- You have no handling for `'.'`.
- An `int` cannot store values with fractional parts.
- You're printing out the entire number on every iteration.
- You aren't initializing `prev` to `0`.

Comment: The handling for not only '.' but also other non-numerics needs to be improved.  It's not enough to add zero, but to also avoid multiplying by 10 for that character and/or give up with an error complaint.

Answer (score 0):

Try it (without sign evaluation and error handling):

```
int main(void)
{
    double x=0,op=0;
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c!='\n')
      if( c=='.' )
        op++;
      else
      if( op )
        x += (op/=10) * intVal(c);
      else
        x = x*10 + intVal(c);

    printf("%f",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does if(op) and op/=10 do?

Comment: They suggest to you that you should read your textbook more closely.

Answer (score 0):

Your function *intVal* is total wrong according to your requirement.

If you want get `<1234>(5)` from `0001234.5`, the easiest way is using `scanf`:

```
sscanf("%d.%d", &a, &b);
printf("<%d>(%d)\n", a, b);
```

see `man scanf`